# What is this Mandalorian helmet/jetpack from?

Tags: star-wars, minifigure-identification

I found this flat silver & blue Mandalorian helmet & jetpack in a mixed bag of minifigs. I'm pretty sure it's not LEGO - there's no LEGO mark or part number and the only thing printed is the number "2" on the inside of the helmet.   There is no color on the jetpack.

All the LEGO Mandalorian parts I found online have the helmet and jetpack as 2 separate parts - this one has them connected.

Can anyone find what non-LEGO set or figure this is from?  I didn't think anyone else had the rights to make Star Wars parts.

[image: Mandalorian Helmet]

Comment: This is probably a clone branded item. LEGO uses jet pack as a separate item: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64802

Comment: The clone-brands are notorious for ignoring licensing rules.  Also, the LEGO Star Wars helmets I glanced at are smooth on the top.  The dimple in the middle of your helmet could be due to lazy injection molding, which is another sign that this is a clone brand item.  That doesn't stop someone from knowing and answering, so we'll see if anybody knows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part# x50px2

[Minifigure, Headgear Helmet SW Rocket Pack with Jango Fett Colors Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x50px2&idColor=66#T=C&C=66)

it belongs to [Jango Fett (Balaclava Head)](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0053/jango-fett-(balaclava-head))

From set [7153-1: Jango Fett's Slave I](https://brickset.com/sets/7153-1/Jango-Fett-s-Slave-I)

Comment: Holy cow - good find. This was not coming up on my searches!

Comment: According to OP "there's no LEGO mark or part number", and the [flashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_%28manufacturing%29) on the visor is a lot more visible than on the pictures in Bricklink; both indicators of a clone part. Does anyone know where the LEGO marking should be on an official part?

Answer (score 3):

It is real LEGO, these old boba fett/jango fett helmet and jetpack assemblies have numbers on the inside and no other markings such as the word LEGO.